# MacBook turning on issue during high humidity

Tags: macbook-pro

For past few days, roughly 30, I've been facing issues with switching on my MacBook Pro 2015 model.

This is what I've observed.
So what happens is if during a day or night there is high humidity, Mac doesn't turn on in case it has been kept in turn off mode for 5-6 hours however as soon as I take it to an air conditioned room, it switches on just in a matter of 2-3 minutes.

Also, if I use hair dryer on it for about 30-40 seconds, it switches on without any further problems.

These problems are being faced only during high humid environment & for other period of time, it works fine. I've done hardware test on my Macbook which doesn't show any issues.

If this helps. It's been two months I've relocated to a more humid area, before that I was not having trouble with my Macbook.

What could be the possible reason for this strange issue? Can anybody help?

Comment: In the Tech Specs for your model, under Electrical and Operating Requirements, two of the Operating requirements are, Operating temperature: 50° to 95° F (10° to 35° C) and Relative humidity: 0% to 90% noncondensing. If the ambient temperature around your MacBook Pro is above 95° F (35° C) and or you have any humidity condensing inside the case of the MacBook Pro then it makes sense you're having issues as you've described.

Comment: BTW I too live in an area that's, depending on the season, subject to high relative humidity reaching 100% over night and condensing to the point you'd thought it rained. Obviously you cannot leave electronic equipment outside and unprotected in these conditions.

Comment: Of course, I'm not keeping it in any kind of unprotected condition. Is it wise to have it checked up by Apple service centre?

Comment: I wasn't implying you were keeping it in any kind of unprotected condition, just commenting on operating temperature and relative humidity and what it's like where I live regarding the humidity. From what you expressed in your OP it sounds like you getting condensation inside the case and therefore you have to stop using it under the conditions that create the issue. Taking it to Apple isn't going to change the circumstances under which the issue is occurring. However, if you want to play it totally safe, then have it checked out.

Comment: I have this same issue. Just moved to a house close to the beach, and the humidity and salt air are definitely the cause. Every time I bring the MacBook into the Apple store it starts working again because of the AC and low humidity.They checked it out and everything hardware is perfectly fine with no water damage whatsoever. It is a shame Apple has no resolution and are not even aware of this issue. My only option is to buy a new laptop and hope the newer MacBooks don’t have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I waited for the sun to come out and dried my MacBook Air in front of fan. Try to keep your laptop in dry conditions. The shutdown might be a safeguard for motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have MacBook Air 13", 2017 model. In 2018 monsoons, I got the logic board changed as Apple store couldn't find any hardware problem and it was under warranty.

Next year, I put MacBook in a box with silica gel for 3 days and it booted up!